# default template parameter - don't have to be from right? Why it works?

Tags: c++, templates, default-parameters

Does default template parameter can use "default value" in a way that does NOT start from right?

What is the criteria?
How will the compiler interpret?

For example, I am so surprised that **this code works**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <bool T=true, class U>   //"default" from LEFT-most parameter
void f(U u){
    if(T){ cout<<true;}
    else cout<<false;
}
int main() {
    auto x = []( ){  };
    f(x);
    return 0;
}
```

See live demo here : https://ideone.com/l6d9du

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Template argument deduction works well here, because for function template, the subsequent template arguments might be deduced by function arguments. In this case, template argument `U` could be deduced from function argument `u`. Note that for class template, as you expected, the subsequent template-parameter after a default template-argument shall either have a default template-argument or be a template parameter pack.

[§14.1/11 Template parameters
[temp.param]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#11):

> If a template-parameter of a class template, variable template, or
> alias template has a default template-argument, each subsequent
> template-parameter shall either have a default template-argument
> supplied or be a template parameter pack. If a template-parameter of a
> primary class template, primary variable template, or alias template
> is a template parameter pack, it shall be the last template-parameter.
> A template parameter pack of a function template shall not be followed
> by another template parameter unless that template parameter can be
> deduced from the parameter-type-list ([dcl.fct]) of the function
> template or has a default argument ([temp.deduct]). A template
> parameter of a deduction guide template ([temp.deduct.guide]) that
> does not have a default argument shall be deducible from the
> parameter-type-list of the deduction guide template. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T1 = int, class T2> class B;   // error
>
> // U can be neither deduced from the parameter-type-list nor specified
> template<class... T, class... U> void f() { } // error
> template<class... T, class U> void g() { }    // error
> ```
>
> — end example ]

You could try to make `U` undeducible and see what will happen:

```
template <bool T=true, class U>   //"default" from LEFT-most parameter
void f(){
    if(T){ cout<<true;}
    else cout<<false;
}
int main() {
    f();            // Fail. Can't deduce U.
    f<true>();      // Fail. Can't deduce U.
    f<true, int>(); // Fine. T=true, U=int.
    return 0;
}
```

Note you have to specify all the template arguments explicitly to make the code work, which makes default template arguments meaningless at all. If you want to make `f()` or `f<true>()` work, you need to give `U` a default template-argument too (or make it template parameter pack).

```
template <bool T=true, class U=int>
void f(){
    if(T){ cout<<true;}
    else cout<<false;
}
int main() {
    f();              // Fine. T=true,  U=int
    f<false>();       // Fine. T=false, U=int
    f<false, char>(); // Fine. T=false, U=char
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can supply a default for any parameter.

If you want to *use* the default, you can't explicitly specify parameters to the right of the defaulted parameter.  However, in your example, `U` is being deduced from the type of the argument to the function, and `T` is being defaulted.